# Loading icon with CSS is always visible

Tags: javascript, html, css

The loading icon is always showing. I need it to check the first JavaScript code and if that's true show a loading icon. What's wrong with my code? On the "onsubmit" part, have I done it wrong by just placing the 2 JavaScript behind eachother?

```js
    function checkForm(form)
    {
     if(form.username.value == "") {
       alert("Error: gelieve je naam in te vullen!");
       form.username.focus();
      return false;
    }
    re = /^\w+$/;
    if(!re.test(form.username.value)) {
      alert("Error: je naam mag alleen letters,nummers, en underscores   bevatten!");
      form.username.focus();
      return false;
    }

    if(form.pwd1.value != "" && form.pwd1.value == form.pwd2.value) {
      if(form.pwd1.value.length < 8) {
        alert("Error: je wachtwoord moet minstens 8 tekens hebben!");
        form.pwd1.focus();
        return false;
      }
      if(form.pwd1.value == form.username.value) {
        alert("Error: je wachtwoord mag niet hetzelfde zijn als je naam!");
        form.pwd1.focus();
        return false;
      }
      re = /[0-9]/;
      if(!re.test(form.pwd1.value)) {
        alert("Error: je wachtwoord moet minstens 1 cijfer bevatten (0-9)!");
        form.pwd1.focus();
        return false;
      }
      re = /[a-z]/;
      if(!re.test(form.pwd1.value)) {
        alert("Error: je wachtwoord moet minstens 1 kleine letter bevatten (a-z)!");
        form.pwd1.focus();
        return false;
      }
      re = /[A-Z]/;
      if(!re.test(form.pwd1.value)) {
        alert("Error: je wachtwoord moet minstens 1 grote letter bevatten (A-Z)!");
        form.pwd1.focus();
        return false;
      }
    } else {
      alert("Error: je ingevulde wachtwoorden zijn niet hetzelfde!");
      form.pwd1.focus();
      return false;
    }

    ;
    return true;
    }
    function showHide() {
    var div = document.getElementById("hidden_div");
    if (div.style.display == 'none') {
    div.style.display = '';
    }
    else {
    div.style.display = 'none';
    return false;
    }
    }
```

```html
    <form name="form" method="POST" action="\JocanasNL.php" onsubmit="return checkForm(this); showHide(); return true;">    
     Voornaam.Achternaam:*<br><input type="text" name="username" size="19" required><br>
    <p>Dit zal ook jouw inlognaam worden!</p><br>
    Geslacht:<br><input type="radio" name="sex" value="Man">Man<br>
    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="Vrouw">Vrouw<br><br>
    Emailadres:*<br><input type="email" name="email" size="19" required><br><br>
    Wachtwoord:*<br><input rows="9" type="password" name="pwd1" size="19" required><br><br>
    Wachtwoord bevestigen:*<br><input rows="9" type="password" name="pwd2" size="19" required><br><br>
    Ideeën voor nieuwe films, TV-series games of functies:<br><textarea class="input" name="comment" rows="5" cols="30"></textarea><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Aanvragen" name="submit">
    <input type="reset" value="Herstellen">
    </form>
    <div class="spinner">
    <div class="bounce1"></div>
    <div class="bounce2"></div>
    <div class="bounce3"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Your `showHide()` function is checking to see whether an element with the ID of `hidden_div` is being displayed or hidden, but I don't see that element in your HTML.

Comment: <div id="hidden_div" style="display:none">
<div class="spinner">
  <div class="bounce1"></div>
  <div class="bounce2"></div>
  <div class="bounce3"></div>
</div>
</div>
Made this improvement but now on submit the icon is never showing however the action is executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code

```
return checkForm(this); showHide(); return true;
```

is incorrect. Since you `return checkForm(this)`, `showHide` will never be executed. Since `showHide` shows it if it was hidden and hides it if it was shown and you always see it, I suppose that somehow your `hidden_div` is getting displayed despite the inline CSS explicitly specifying that it will not be displayed, either through `checkForm` or through other means. You need to check the generated HTML via dev tools to confirm or deny this statement.

The code above should be changed to

```
if (checkForm(this)) {showHide(); return true;} return false;
```

so if `checkForm` is `true`, `showHide` is called and `true` is returned, meaning that the `form` will be posted. Otherwise `false` is returned, preventing the `form` from being posted.